# C macro to enable and disable code features

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I've used a code base before that had a macro system for enabling and disabling sections of code.  It looked something like the following:

```
#define IN_USE      X
#define NOT_IN_USE  _

#if defined( WIN32 )
    #define FEATURE_A       IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_B       IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_C       NOT_IN_USE
#elif defined( OSX )
    #define FEATURE_A       NOT_IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_B       NOT_IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_C       IN_USE
#else
    #define FEATURE_A       NOT_IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_B       NOT_IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_C       NOT_IN_USE
#endif
```

Then the code for the features would look like:

```
void DoFeatures()
{
#if USING( FEATURE_A )
    // Feature A code...
#endif

#if USING( FEATURE_B )
    // Feature B code...
#endif

#if USING( FEATURE_C )
    // Feature C code...
#endif

#if USING( FEATURE_D ) // Compile error since FEATURE_D was never defined
    // Feature D code...
#endif
}
```

My question (the part I don't remember) is how to define the 'USING' macro so that it errors if the feature hasn't been defined as 'IN_USE' or 'NOT_IN_USE'? Which could be the case if you forget to include the correct header file.

```
#define USING( feature ) ((feature == IN_USE) ? 1 : ((feature == NOT_IN_USE) ? 0 : COMPILE_ERROR?))
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused at the existence of `IN_USE` and `NOT_IN_USE`.

Comment: I believe it was just to make things more readable.  You could just as easily define the features as 'X' and '_' or any other random character(s) as long as the USING macro used the same.

Comment: Why you don't just remove the NOT_IN_USE define?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  How would that cause an error if the feature wasn't defined, such as FEATURE_D in the example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example already achieves what you want, since `#if USING(x)` will produce an error message if `USING` isn't defined. All you need in your header file is something like

```
#define IN_USE 1
#define NOT_IN_USE 0
#define USING(feature) feature
```

If you want to be sure that you also get an error just for doing something like

```
#if FEATURE
```

or

```
#if USING(UNDEFINED_MISPELED_FEETURE)
```

then you could do, say,

```
#define IN_USE == 1
#define NOT_IN_USE == 0
#define USING(feature) 1 feature
```

but you won't be able to prevent such misuse as

```
#ifdef FEATURE
```

Comment: I want the error if the feature isn't defined, not the USING macro.  Such as FEATURE_D in my example.

Comment: @0x48492121 Like I said: "or #if USING(fred) where fred isn't a feature". Also, you said that you want to detect not including the header file ... like I said, if the header file isn't included, you will get an error an any occurrence of #if USING(...)

Comment: @0x48492121 Again: `#if USING(FEATURE_D)` will produce an error message using my second proposal: *error: missing binary operator before token "FEATURE_D"* ... and if you don't like that proposal, there's an infinity of similar ones.

Comment: Ah.. Sorry I missed understood the fred part.  Seems to work.  I'm confused with what "#define USING(feature) 1 feature" is actually doing.

Comment: @0x48492121 feature is either `== 1` or `== 0`, so it produces `1 == 1` or `1 == 0`. This should be clear if you understand that the preprocessor just does textual (or token) substitution.

Comment: @0x48492121 It might be clearer to reverse it, using `1 ==` and `0 ==`, and `feature 1`. Again, there's an infinity of variations. All you need is for the pieces to not be legal expressions by themselves.

Comment: @0x48492121 Because the preprocessor evaluates undefined variables as 0, and `1 == 0` is valid syntax. Again, you need for all the definitions to be invalid syntax on their own ... `feature == 1` looks valid, which defeats the point. P.S. be sure to include @name in comments ... it's sheer coincidence that I saw this.

Answer (score 1):

The following works. It will give you compile error for FEATURE_D. If you comment out the code for FEATURE_D, then it will execute code for FEATURE_A and FEATURE_B. The code is pretty much self-explanatory. Instead of checking whether FEATURE_D or others are defined inside DoFeatures function, you can just put them inside an if block. In that way, the compiler will try to execute the code block. If it is 1, then the code inside if block will get executed; in case of 0, it will not get executed. And if it is never defined, then will get a compile error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN_USE      1
#define NOT_IN_USE  0

#define FEATURE_A       IN_USE
#define FEATURE_B       IN_USE
#define FEATURE_C       NOT_IN_USE


void DoFeatures()
{
    if(FEATURE_A){
        // Feature A code...
        printf("Feature A\n");
    }

    if(FEATURE_B){
        // Feature B code...
        printf("Feature B\n");
    }

    if(FEATURE_C){
        // Feature C code...
        printf("Feature C\n");
    }

    if(FEATURE_D) {// Compile error since FEATURE_D was never defined
        // Feature D code...
        printf("Feature D\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DoFeatures();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works, but it won't remove the code from being compiled and adds unnecessary runtime checks.

Comment: @0x48492121 There are no unnecessary runtime checks if you optimize (and you're not caring about time if you don't), but it doesn't solve the problem when code must be removed because there would be syntax errors or other problems otherwise.

Comment: @JimBalter, I don't get this part "doesn't solve the problem when code must be removed because there would be syntax errors" because the question says: "it errors if the feature hasn't been defined as 'IN_USE' or 'NOT_IN_USE'? Which could be the case if you forget to include the correct header file." and I think I have ensured this error checking.

Comment: The two things you're quoting have nothing to do with each other. The OP wants preprocessor `#if`, not C language level `if(...)`. Preprocessor ifdefs are often used at file level, where your expressions cannot be used, or to comment out code that depends on typedefs or other declarations that aren't available so the code would generate syntax errors ... putting it inside `if(0) { ... }` doesn't affect the syntax checker.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't define it if it is not in use

```
#if defined( WIN32 )
    #define FEATURE_A       
    #define FEATURE_B       
#else if defined( OSX )
    #define FEATURE_C      
#else

#endif
```

Then In you code:

```
void DoFeatures()
{
#ifdef FEATURE_A
    // Feature A code...
#endif

#ifdef FEATURE_B
    // Feature B code...
#endif

#ifdef FEATURE_C
    // Feature C code...
#endif

#ifdef FEATURE_D // Compile error since FEATURE_D was never defined
    // Feature D code...
#endif
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to generate an error if the feature isn't defined.  if "#define FEATURE_A" is in some header and you check "#ifdef FEATURE_A" without including the header, it will silently skip that code.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use another group of `#ifdef`s?

```
#if defined(WIN32)
    #define FEATURE_A
    #define FEATURE_B
#elif defined (OSX)
    #define FEATURE_C
#endif

// ...

#if defined(FEATURE_A)
    do_a();
#endif
```

etc.

Comment: I'm trying to generate an error if the feature isn't defined.  This was to prevent typos such as: "#if defined(FAETURE_A)" or if the you forget to include the header that defines the feature.

Comment: @0x48492121 Then `#define FEATURE_A` to 1 or 0, depending on if it is or isn't present, then inside the `#ifdef FEATURE_A`, insert another level of conditionals: `#if FEATURE_A`. Then, the `#else` part of the `#ifdef` should contain an `#error "feature inclusion typo detected"`.

Comment: The USING macro is to keep the code cleaner by not having the additional level of conditionals.

Comment: @0x48492121 You know you **just** accepted an answer that's essentially a copy of mine, some 23 minutes *later?*

Comment: I did?  I must of missed something.  I don't see how your answer generates the error when FEATURE_D isn't defined.

Comment: @JimBalter Pipe it through `cpp -E` then think about it. It's almost exactly the same.

Comment: @H2CO3 The only thing I can figure is that you're looking at something other than my answer, because they aren't at all the same, and it would be irrelevant if cpp -E produced similar output, but that's not even close to the case. Your answer doesn't have anything to do with what the OP asked for, and doesn't meet the OP's requirements. e.g., if the user mistypes `#if defined(FEETURE_A)`, the compiler is silent, whereas `#if USING(FEETURE_A)` with my solution produces an error message.

Comment: "but that's not even close to the case" -- Let me rephrase that. If the user doesn't do anything wrong and defines the right symbols, then any of these solutions are going to produce exactly the same cpp -E output ... but's that's utterly irrelevant; we're talking about a preprocessor solution, and whatever solution that is will *disappear* in the cpp -E output. But it won't disappear if the solution does what the OP wants and *results in a preprocessor error message* ... in that case the cpp -E output is radically different.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define IN_USE      1
//#define NOT_IN_USE  _  //Not required


#if defined( WIN32 )
    #define FEATURE_A       IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_B       IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_C       NOT_IN_USE
#elif defined( OSX )
    #define FEATURE_A       NOT_IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_B       NOT_IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_C       IN_USE
#else
    #define FEATURE_A       NOT_IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_B       NOT_IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_C       NOT_IN_USE
#endif

#define USING( feature ) feature
```

And then your code

Comment: I want the compiler to error if the USING macro is used with a feature that isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
#define IN_USE      1
#define NOT_IN_USE  0

#if defined( WIN32 )
    #define FEATURE_A       IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_B       IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_C       NOT_IN_USE
#elif defined( OSX )
    #define FEATURE_A       NOT_IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_B       NOT_IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_C       IN_USE
#else
    #define FEATURE_A       NOT_IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_B       NOT_IN_USE
    #define FEATURE_C       NOT_IN_USE
#endif

#define USING(f) ((f == IN_USE) ? 1 : (f == NOT_IN_USE) ? 0 : (f))

#include <stdio.h>

void DoFeatures()
{
#if USING( FEATURE_A )
    // Feature A code...
    printf("Feature A\n");
#endif

#if USING( FEATURE_B )
    // Feature B code...
    printf("Feature B\n");
#endif

#if USING( FEATURE_C )
    // Feature C code...
    printf("Feature C\n");
#endif

#if defined( FEATURE_D ) // Compile error since FEATURE_D was never defined
    // Feature D code...
    printf("Feature D\n");
#else
#error FEATURE_D not defined.
#endif
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DoFeatures();
    return 0;
}
```

For the compilation error, I have no idea how to integrate it into the macro.  It would be appreciated if somebody could shed us some light.  :P

Comment: I know it's possible, just don't know how to integrate it either.